# Get data from URL to pass to another page in NextJS with Typescript, AppRouter

Tags: typescript, next.js, app-router

I'm having changing page from Home to Detail, i already passed data to URL from Home screen, but in Detail screen i can not get it.
I'm using NextJS ver 13, with Typescript and App Router.
I tried to use { useRouter } from "next/router" but it has deprecated in my version.
I'm now using { useParams } from "next/navigation" but I'm not clear how to use it. Please help me !!!

Here's my code:
app/page.tsx:

```
'use client'

import Link from "next/link";
import Heading from "../Components/Heading";
import { data } from "autoprefixer";
import Router from "next/router";
import { send } from "process";
import type { NextPage } from "next";

export default function HomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Heading>iOS Team</Heading>
      <ul className="px-5">
        {iOS.map(member =>
          <li>
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: "/Detail",
                query: member
              }}>{member.account}</Link>
          </li>
        )}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

list member:

```
export const listMember = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "name1",
    age: 20,
  },
    {
    id: 2,
    name: "name2",
    age: 18,
  },
    {
    id: 3,
    name: "name3",
    age: 2,
  }
]
```

Detail screen:

```
'use client'

import HomePage,{ listMember } from "../page";
import { useParams } from "next/navigation";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function DetailMember() {

    const params = useParams();
    const member = listMember.find((item) => item.id === parseInt(params.id));
    console.log(params)

    return (
        <>
        <h1>
        This is detail page of {member?.account}
        </h1>
        </>
    )
}
```

Tried to use "useParams" but not work

Comment: what is iOS? it seems it's an array. please give more info about it and where it exists?

Comment: sory, my bad. It's actually:  {listMember.map(member =>
          <li>
            <Link
              href={{
                pathname: "/Detail",
                query: member
              }}>{member.account}</Link>
          </li>

Comment: useParams() is used for dynamic parameters. useSearchParams() should be used instead.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you passed in your member object in the `<Link/>` component as "query", you should be using [useSearchParams](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/use-search-params) instead, which will get the query string.

```
const params = useSearchParams();
const id = params.get('id');
```

Comment: @MinhDat Glad it worked for you, if you don't mind you can help to mark the answer as accepted :)